# Change selection after inserting xml text in Word Interop App

Tags: office-interop

I have a word addin that creates a list of fields that can be place in a word document.  When you select a field either by drag and drop or doubleclick, it places that field on the document and an xml part is creaed inside the document.  That works fine.  What I want to do is move the selection position in word to be after the xml part that was just inserted.  So if the field said "date created", I want to move the selection point to be the following line after "date created".  Any ideas on how to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using a range to insert the field? 
if so you can collapse to the end of the range then add what you want. 
Example:

```
// Move to the end
myRange.Collapse(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
// Now add something behind the table to prevent word from joining tables into one
myRange.InsertParagraphAfter();
//to move to the end again
myRange.Collapse(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
```